# Redis ReplyError(string) when passing floating point number

Tags: javascript, redis

When I am passing a floating point number `-3.074` to `hincrby` I am getting this error.

> ReplyError: ERR value is not an integer or out of range

Code

```js
console.log(typeof sizeInMB, sizeInMB) // number -3.074
redis.hincrby('MYHASH', 'storage', sizeInMB) // throws above error
```

I am very new to redis, forgive me if I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by changing `hincrby` to `hincrbyfloat`